# Add backend pool with targets (virtual machine) in Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-java-sdk

I am looking for Java API to use, by which I can add backend pool with virtual machines details inside a existing a ApplicationGateway. Please help me.

Comment: What did you try? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-gateway/applicationgateways/createorupdate

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for modifying an existing Azure Application gateway using an API (also adding / updating backend pools) is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-gateway/applicationgateways/createorupdate

Comment: Using azure console I have created a Application Gateway with backend pools (targetType="Virtual machine", target="mynetworkInterfaceName") and now trying to update this backend pool with Java sdk API using `myApplicationGateway.update().updateBackend("mybackendpool").withIPAddress("someIP")`  which is working. But I'm looking to update/add targetType="Virtual machine" types pool. which Java class has support this requirement. Please help. Thanks in advance!